# Motion Layout : How to Animate Card / Nested Layout height while expanding and collapsing

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 beta 4

In Motion-Layout while doing :

- scaling transformation or
- the position change of elements by changing the constraints or
- gone -> visibility transition

The height of the layout/card(with height = wrap content) only changes after the expansion/collapse, which results in hiding part of the animation(Since the height has not increased the animation gets hidden after it crosses the boundary of the layout) or a weird transition at the end depending on the Animation.

How to expand/collapse the height of parent layout/card concurrently with the transition of elements.